# How to access a value which is associated with a dropdownlist item?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

This is my dropdown list code........

```
<td valign="top" align="center">
   <asp:DropDownList ID="StudentNameDropDownList" runat="server" Width="150px" 
       DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2" DataTextField="StudentName" 
       DataValueField="StudentName" AutoPostBack="True">
   </asp:DropDownList>
   <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
       ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:dbbilling2.0ConnectionString3 %>" 

       SelectCommand="SELECT [StudentID], [StudentName] FROM [tblStudentInfo] WHERE ([Class] = @Class)">
       <SelectParameters>
           <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ClassDropDownList" Name="Class" 
               PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="String" />
       </SelectParameters>
   </asp:SqlDataSource>
   <br />
```

Now I want to access the Student ID field in my code behind file..How can i achieve this?? What syntax i must use[like dropdownlist.selecteditem] ??

Comment: set data value field student id ....than use selected value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all in your DropDownList asp component you must set the property  DataValueField="StudentID", then in your code behind you can get the Id of the selected student by writing : StudentNameDropDownList.SelectedValue

Answer (score 0):

For Id You can try this code

```
StudentNameDropDownList.SelectedValue
```